# How to return XML response in Web API

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

Happy new year everyobdy, 
After I serialize object using StringWriter and return output response and send to client. But when client receive the response:
It has a tag like this:

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/...">
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16">
   <trx>.....</trx>
</string>
```

So, my questions are:
 1. How should I return the correct format xml like below:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16">
       <trx>.....</trx>
```

2.   If I send the response as byte[] using MemoryStream, does the client receive correct with encoding="utf-8" ?

Thank you so much! 
This is the code path I used for serializing:

```
StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter();
XmlWriter tw = null;
XmlWriterSettings settings new XmlWriterSettings{
   Encoding =UnicodeEncoding.UTF8,
   Indent =false,
   OmitXmlDeclaration =false
};
var serialize1 =new XmlSerializer(typeof(OTrx));
XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
ns.Add("","");
tw=XmlWriter.Create(textWriter,settings);
serializer1.Serialize(tw,oTrx,ns);
var output=textWriter.ToString();
return output
```

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet showing how you're doing your serialization. You simply state 'using StringWriter'. Also, regarding #2, it depends on how you're creating your response, so would need a code snippet of that as well to help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are using .net core. 
If yes, then you can use this middleware nuget package - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml

Please refer this URL for c[ode examples and detailed explanation.](https://andrewlock.net/formatting-response-data-as-xml-or-json-based-on-the-url-in-asp-net-core/)

Comment: I'm not use .NET core :(

Comment: Please refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11662028/webapi-to-return-xml).  Your header decides whether api will send JSOn or XML.

Comment: So what I need to do is just return the output serialize object, no need to care about the response type cus it's depend on the client side request header ?

Comment: You just need to return serializable object.  Based on http headers  either xml or json would be returned.

Comment: So I just need to return the output object ? but when I test using Postman, I cannot see the output as Xml like the format.

Comment: you mean in the code, I just need to do like this:
return oTrx; ?

Comment: As far as I understand, yes.  You can just rturnnobject. Try  and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful if you shared some sample code but have you considered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11662028/webapi-to-return-xml)?

> If you return a string, you'll get a string.

Comment: Yes, I want to return the output like below, so what should I return the type of output:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16">
       <trx>.....</trx>