# Single Web API request which accepts all type of inputs in C#

Tags: c#, http, post, asp.net-core-webapi

I designe a request which will accept all the types of inputs like XML, JSON, etc. 
Accordingly the method will respond and will give the corresponding output. 
Is there any example on that?

I have tried the below code.

When I call it from Postman it is giving  a

> **415 ERROR**.

```
[HttpPost("/GetOutput", Name = nameof(GetOutput))]
[Consumes("application/xml","application/json", "text/plain")]        
public IActionResult GetOutput(dynamic request)
{
    //process         
    return new ObjectResult(res.ToString());
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `[FromBody]dynamic`?

Comment: 415 is Unsupported Media Type. What are you posting?

Answer (score 0):

Allowing a user to submit *all the types of input* can be a super-dangerous idea. You never know what your users will submit.

If you just want to accept a text-based input, like what your example is trying to do , accepting `json/xml/text`, you can try this:

**1. Define a binding model. No `dynamic`:**

```cs
public class MyRequestBindingModel
{
    // the type of Content.
    public string Type { get; set; }

    // the serialized json/xml/text content.
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

**2. Your controller action:**

```cs
[HttpPost("/GetOutput")]
public IActionResult GetOutput([FromBody] MyRequestBindingModel request)
{
    // process
    switch(request.Type.ToLower())
    {
        case "json": _processJsonInput(request.Content); 
        case "xml": _processXmlInput(request.Content); 
        default: _processTextInput(request.Content); 
    }

    // do something else you want
}
```

The `switch` statement in the above example is just showing an idea on how to handle the string content base on the `Type` provided.

If you want to return XML if the `Content` in the API call is XML, this answer may be helpful: 
[Helpful Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23055995/13742790).